How to get cookie information of chrome in local storage
I'm going to get my cookie information of chrome in my local storage.(if possible, programmatically)
It doesn't mean finding at google developer console. I'm using windows operating system.
Please guide or teach some guidance to implement this.
Thanks
I tried to get cache data at local storage, but I can't find tool and method to analyze it.
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\Cache_Data
